# load webpage in several parts using ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to load a webpage in several parts, maybe using jquery ajax or just simple javascript ajax functions so the user can start interacting with the webpage withouth having to wait for the whole page to load. Just like gmail does.

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: This question is way too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to dedicate some div containers for inserting dynamically loaded contents.

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Then you can load other pages on startup.

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').load('content.php');
    $('#content').load('sidebar.php');
});
```

Of course this is only a start. You have to check for errors on loading and retry. Also using hash value you can dynamically load content & sidebar. etc..